# Does the order in a circular arrangement matter?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I posted a question a while ago:

> Ten chairs are arranged in a circle. Find the number of subsets of this set of chairs that contain at least three adjacent chairs.

My question here is: imagine a circle with ten chairs and an $x$ for occupied chair which is at the very top.

> If we moved that occupied chair $x$ to the very right (third chair space) and change nothing else, **so basically rotate the arrange a little bit** does it count as a full new arrangement or is it the same?

Comment: @trueblueanil nono, I am just asking if it is a different arrangement

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What do you mean by adjacent chairs ? In a circle, each chair has 2 adjacent to it. Are some chairs occupied and some empty and do you mean 3 adjacent occupied chairs? Is *x* for occupied chair which is at the top a reference point for the other chairs ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're counting based on the relative position of the people sitting at the table, nothing would change; since every time you want to sit $n$ people at a circular table, there are $(n-1)!$ ways of doing so. The first person to sit has only one available position, because no matter where he/she sits, the number of people sitting at his/her right or left will continue to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether an arrangement of chairs in a circle changes if you *rotate* it, the answer is that it doesn't. But if *x* is a special chair serving as a reference point (sort of *head of table*) shifting *x* alone will be a changed arrangement.